# Sequence contains more than one matching element after upgrading my .NET LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods..cctor()

I'm getting the error after upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6

below is the query

```
 var result = _context.Set<Assessment>()
            .Count(a => a.Deleted == false);
 return result;
```

try to execute

```
 var result = _context.Set<Assessment>()
            .Count(a => a.Deleted == false);
 return result;
```

Comment: What's the *actual* full exception text? The error occurs in a static constructor, before that query gets evaluated at all - before *any* LINQ query gets evaluated. EF Core is open source so you can actually look at the error's location to see what caused the problem. In any case, EF Core *5* is *unsupported* which means no bugs will be fixed. You'll have to upgrade to EF Core 6 anyway

Comment: May be related to [this issue reported at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24002).

Answer (score 2):

Try updating EF Core too. Either to the latest 5.x version or (I would argue) much better to 6.x. .NET 6 has new `Queryable` methods added which resulted in a bug in EF Core internal reflection code  for older versions.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the posted code. The message itself talks about `Enumerable.Single`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exception comes from  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods..cctor()` I doubt it has anything to do with user code.

Comment: That's a static constructor which means it's still not related to the query. I wonder what kind of a mixup would bypass package version checks and end up causing issues in the static constructor.

Comment: Agree with @PanagiotisKanavos. Such sort of silly bugs just after updating from .NET5 to .NET6, are you serious, OP?

Comment: @Ryan It's not that simple. I didn't have such problems when I upgraded from EF Core 5 to 6. This must be a more complex issue, probably involving *indirect* dependencies. Otherwise .NET Core itself would either complain about conflicting versions, or use *one* version and issue a warning.

Comment: In any case, EF Core 5 is unsupported so upgrading to 6 is the only way forward